# Mediapipe facemesh vertices mapping

Tags: mediapipe

I am trying to use Google's Mediapipe face mesh in my custom graphic engine for a personal project. I found that there is a face mesh picture that indicates the mapping from the landmarks index to the face mesh location.

[image]

However, there are 486 landmarks in total, so it will take a while to manually figure out all the triangles' landmarks. Is there a vertices mapping file that I can use to load the vertices mapping from?

Something like:

```
[
   [  0, 267, 164],
   [  0, 164,  37],
   [  0,  37,  72],
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found this in Mediapipe's source code.
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/face_mesh_connections.py
The FACEMESH_TESSELATION frozenset in the code defines the point-to-point connection pair between all points. However, the **connection pairs are not the same as the ones in the picture** [image: Mediapipe facemesh] provided by Mediapipe. Some connections in the picture are not defined in the code, some connections in code are not defined in the picture. Nevertheless, it's good enough for my application, so I wrote a simple program to generate the vertice tuples from it. The result is in the given json string. You're welcome to copy it if it helps.

```
[
    [127,  34, 139],
    [ 11,   0,  37],
    [232, 231, 120],
    [ 72,  37,  39],
    [128, 121,  47],
    [232, 121, 128],
    [104,  69,  67],
    [175, 171, 148],
    [118,  50, 101],
    [ 73,  39,  40],
    [  9, 151, 108],
    [ 48, 115, 131],
    [194, 204, 211],
    [ 74,  40, 185],
    [ 80,  42, 183],
    [ 40,  92, 186],
    [230, 229, 118],
    [202, 212, 214],
    [ 83,  18,  17],
    [ 76,  61, 146],
    [160,  29,  30],
    [ 56, 157, 173],
    [106, 204, 194],
    [135, 214, 192],
    [203, 165,  98],
    [ 21,  71,  68],
    [ 51,  45,   4],
    [144,  24,  23],
    [ 77, 146,  91],
    [205,  50, 187],
    [201, 200,  18],
    [ 91, 106, 182],
    [ 90,  91, 181],
    [ 85,  84,  17],
    [206, 203,  36],
    [148, 171, 140],
    [ 92,  40,  39],
    [193, 189, 244],
    [159, 158,  28],
    [247, 246, 161],
    [236,   3, 196],
    [ 54,  68, 104],
    [193, 168,   8],
    [117, 228,  31],
    [189, 193,  55],
    [ 98,  97,  99],
    [126,  47, 100],
    [166,  79, 218],
    [155, 154,  26],
    [209,  49, 131],
    [135, 136, 150],
    [ 47, 126, 217],
    [223,  52,  53],
    [ 45,  51, 134],
    [211, 170, 140],
    [ 67,  69, 108],
    [ 43, 106,  91],
    [230, 119, 120],
    [226, 130, 247],
    [ 63,  53,  52],
    [238,  20, 242],
    [ 46,  70, 156],
    [ 78,  62,  96],
    [ 46,  53,  63],
    [143,  34, 227],
    [123, 117, 111],
    [ 44, 125,  19],
    [236, 134,  51],
    [216, 206, 205],
    [154, 153,  22],
    [ 39,  37, 167],
    [200, 201, 208],
    [ 36, 142, 100],
    [ 57, 212, 202],
    [ 20,  60,  99],
    [ 28, 158, 157],
    [ 35, 226, 113],
    [160, 159,  27],
    [204, 202, 210],
    [113, 225,  46],
    [ 43, 202, 204],
    [ 62,  76,  77],
    [137, 123, 116],
    [ 41,  38,  72],
    [203, 129, 142],
    [ 64,  98, 240],
    [ 49, 102,  64],
    [ 41,  73,  74],
    [212, 216, 207],
    [ 42,  74, 184],
    [169, 170, 211],
    [170, 149, 176],
    [105,  66,  69],
    [122,   6, 168],
    [123, 147, 187],
    [ 96,  77,  90],
    [ 65,  55, 107],
    [ 89,  90, 180],
    [101, 100, 120],
    [ 63, 105, 104],
    [ 93, 137, 227],
    [ 15,  86,  85],
    [129, 102,  49],
    [ 14,  87,  86],
    [ 55,   8,   9],
    [100,  47, 121],
    [145,  23,  22],
    [ 88,  89, 179],
    [  6, 122, 196],
    [ 88,  95,  96],
    [138, 172, 136],
    [215,  58, 172],
    [115,  48, 219],
    [ 42,  80,  81],
    [195,   3,  51],
    [ 43, 146,  61],
    [171, 175, 199],
    [ 81,  82,  38],
    [ 53,  46, 225],
    [144, 163, 110],
    [ 52,  65,  66],
    [229, 228, 117],
    [ 34, 127, 234],
    [107, 108,  69],
    [109, 108, 151],
    [ 48,  64, 235],
    [ 62,  78, 191],
    [129, 209, 126],
    [111,  35, 143],
    [117, 123,  50],
    [222,  65,  52],
    [ 19, 125, 141],
    [221,  55,  65],
    [  3, 195, 197],
    [ 25,   7,  33],
    [220, 237,  44],
    [ 70,  71, 139],
    [122, 193, 245],
    [247, 130,  33],
    [ 71,  21, 162],
    [170, 169, 150],
    [188, 174, 196],
    [216, 186,  92],
    [  2,  97, 167],
    [141, 125, 241],
    [164, 167,  37],
    [ 72,  38,  12],
    [ 38,  82,  13],
    [ 63,  68,  71],
    [226,  35, 111],
    [101,  50, 205],
    [206,  92, 165],
    [209, 198, 217],
    [165, 167,  97],
    [220, 115, 218],
    [133, 112, 243],
    [239, 238, 241],
    [214, 135, 169],
    [190, 173, 133],
    [171, 208,  32],
    [125,  44, 237],
    [ 86,  87, 178],
    [ 85,  86, 179],
    [ 84,  85, 180],
    [ 83,  84, 181],
    [201,  83, 182],
    [137,  93, 132],
    [ 76,  62, 183],
    [ 61,  76, 184],
    [ 57,  61, 185],
    [212,  57, 186],
    [214, 207, 187],
    [ 34, 143, 156],
    [ 79, 239, 237],
    [123, 137, 177],
    [ 44,   1,   4],
    [201, 194,  32],
    [ 64, 102, 129],
    [213, 215, 138],
    [ 59, 166, 219],
    [242,  99,  97],
    [  2,  94, 141],
    [ 75,  59, 235],
    [ 24, 110, 228],
    [ 25, 130, 226],
    [ 23,  24, 229],
    [ 22,  23, 230],
    [ 26,  22, 231],
    [112,  26, 232],
    [189, 190, 243],
    [221,  56, 190],
    [ 28,  56, 221],
    [ 27,  28, 222],
    [ 29,  27, 223],
    [ 30,  29, 224],
    [247,  30, 225],
    [238,  79,  20],
    [166,  59,  75],
    [ 60,  75, 240],
    [147, 177, 215],
    [ 20,  79, 166],
    [187, 147, 213],
    [112, 233, 244],
    [233, 128, 245],
    [128, 114, 188],
    [114, 217, 174],
    [131, 115, 220],
    [217, 198, 236],
    [198, 131, 134],
    [177, 132,  58],
    [143,  35, 124],
    [110, 163,   7],
    [228, 110,  25],
    [356, 389, 368],
    [ 11, 302, 267],
    [452, 350, 349],
    [302, 303, 269],
    [357, 343, 277],
    [452, 453, 357],
    [333, 332, 297],
    [175, 152, 377],
    [347, 348, 330],
    [303, 304, 270],
    [  9, 336, 337],
    [278, 279, 360],
    [418, 262, 431],
    [304, 408, 409],
    [310, 415, 407],
    [270, 409, 410],
    [450, 348, 347],
    [422, 430, 434],
    [313, 314,  17],
    [306, 307, 375],
    [387, 388, 260],
    [286, 414, 398],
    [335, 406, 418],
    [364, 367, 416],
    [423, 358, 327],
    [251, 284, 298],
    [281,   5,   4],
    [373, 374, 253],
    [307, 320, 321],
    [425, 427, 411],
    [421, 313,  18],
    [321, 405, 406],
    [320, 404, 405],
    [315,  16,  17],
    [426, 425, 266],
    [377, 400, 369],
    [322, 391, 269],
    [417, 465, 464],
    [386, 257, 258],
    [466, 260, 388],
    [456, 399, 419],
    [284, 332, 333],
    [417, 285,   8],
    [346, 340, 261],
    [413, 441, 285],
    [327, 460, 328],
    [355, 371, 329],
    [392, 439, 438],
    [382, 341, 256],
    [429, 420, 360],
    [364, 394, 379],
    [277, 343, 437],
    [443, 444, 283],
    [275, 440, 363],
    [431, 262, 369],
    [297, 338, 337],
    [273, 375, 321],
    [450, 451, 349],
    [446, 342, 467],
    [293, 334, 282],
    [458, 461, 462],
    [276, 353, 383],
    [308, 324, 325],
    [276, 300, 293],
    [372, 345, 447],
    [352, 345, 340],
    [274,   1,  19],
    [456, 248, 281],
    [436, 427, 425],
    [381, 256, 252],
    [269, 391, 393],
    [200, 199, 428],
    [266, 330, 329],
    [287, 273, 422],
    [250, 462, 328],
    [258, 286, 384],
    [265, 353, 342],
    [387, 259, 257],
    [424, 431, 430],
    [342, 353, 276],
    [273, 335, 424],
    [292, 325, 307],
    [366, 447, 345],
    [271, 303, 302],
    [423, 266, 371],
    [294, 455, 460],
    [279, 278, 294],
    [271, 272, 304],
    [432, 434, 427],
    [272, 407, 408],
    [394, 430, 431],
    [395, 369, 400],
    [334, 333, 299],
    [351, 417, 168],
    [352, 280, 411],
    [325, 319, 320],
    [295, 296, 336],
    [319, 403, 404],
    [330, 348, 349],
    [293, 298, 333],
    [323, 454, 447],
    [ 15,  16, 315],
    [358, 429, 279],
    [ 14,  15, 316],
    [285, 336,   9],
    [329, 349, 350],
    [374, 380, 252],
    [318, 402, 403],
    [  6, 197, 419],
    [318, 319, 325],
    [367, 364, 365],
    [435, 367, 397],
    [344, 438, 439],
    [272, 271, 311],
    [195,   5, 281],
    [273, 287, 291],
    [396, 428, 199],
    [311, 271, 268],
    [283, 444, 445],
    [373, 254, 339],
    [282, 334, 296],
    [449, 347, 346],
    [264, 447, 454],
    [336, 296, 299],
    [338,  10, 151],
    [278, 439, 455],
    [292, 407, 415],
    [358, 371, 355],
    [340, 345, 372],
    [346, 347, 280],
    [442, 443, 282],
    [ 19,  94, 370],
    [441, 442, 295],
    [248, 419, 197],
    [263, 255, 359],
    [440, 275, 274],
    [300, 383, 368],
    [351, 412, 465],
    [263, 467, 466],
    [301, 368, 389],
    [395, 378, 379],
    [412, 351, 419],
    [436, 426, 322],
    [  2, 164, 393],
    [370, 462, 461],
    [164,   0, 267],
    [302,  11,  12],
    [268,  12,  13],
    [293, 300, 301],
    [446, 261, 340],
    [330, 266, 425],
    [426, 423, 391],
    [429, 355, 437],
    [391, 327, 326],
    [440, 457, 438],
    [341, 382, 362],
    [459, 457, 461],
    [434, 430, 394],
    [414, 463, 362],
    [396, 369, 262],
    [354, 461, 457],
    [316, 403, 402],
    [315, 404, 403],
    [314, 405, 404],
    [313, 406, 405],
    [421, 418, 406],
    [366, 401, 361],
    [306, 408, 407],
    [291, 409, 408],
    [287, 410, 409],
    [432, 436, 410],
    [434, 416, 411],
    [264, 368, 383],
    [309, 438, 457],
    [352, 376, 401],
    [274, 275,   4],
    [421, 428, 262],
    [294, 327, 358],
    [433, 416, 367],
    [289, 455, 439],
    [462, 370, 326],
    [  2, 326, 370],
    [305, 460, 455],
    [254, 449, 448],
    [255, 261, 446],
    [253, 450, 449],
    [252, 451, 450],
    [256, 452, 451],
    [341, 453, 452],
    [413, 464, 463],
    [441, 413, 414],
    [258, 442, 441],
    [257, 443, 442],
    [259, 444, 443],
    [260, 445, 444],
    [467, 342, 445],
    [459, 458, 250],
    [289, 392, 290],
    [290, 328, 460],
    [376, 433, 435],
    [250, 290, 392],
    [411, 416, 433],
    [341, 463, 464],
    [453, 464, 465],
    [357, 465, 412],
    [343, 412, 399],
    [360, 363, 440],
    [437, 399, 456],
    [420, 456, 363],
    [401, 435, 288],
    [372, 383, 353],
    [339, 255, 249],
    [448, 261, 255],
    [133, 243, 190],
    [133, 155, 112],
    [ 33, 246, 247],
    [ 33, 130,  25],
    [398, 384, 286],
    [362, 398, 414],
    [362, 463, 341],
    [263, 359, 467],
    [263, 249, 255],
    [466, 467, 260],
    [ 75,  60, 166],
    [238, 239,  79],
    [162, 127, 139],
    [ 72,  11,  37],
    [121, 232, 120],
    [ 73,  72,  39],
    [114, 128,  47],
    [233, 232, 128],
    [103, 104,  67],
    [152, 175, 148],
    [119, 118, 101],
    [ 74,  73,  40],
    [107,   9, 108],
    [ 49,  48, 131],
    [ 32, 194, 211],
    [184,  74, 185],
    [191,  80, 183],
    [185,  40, 186],
    [119, 230, 118],
    [210, 202, 214],
    [ 84,  83,  17],
    [ 77,  76, 146],
    [161, 160,  30],
    [190,  56, 173],
    [182, 106, 194],
    [138, 135, 192],
    [129, 203,  98],
    [ 54,  21,  68],
    [  5,  51,   4],
    [145, 144,  23],
    [ 90,  77,  91],
    [207, 205, 187],
    [ 83, 201,  18],
    [181,  91, 182],
    [180,  90, 181],
    [ 16,  85,  17],
    [205, 206,  36],
    [176, 148, 140],
    [165,  92,  39],
    [245, 193, 244],
    [ 27, 159,  28],
    [ 30, 247, 161],
    [174, 236, 196],
    [103,  54, 104],
    [ 55, 193,   8],
    [111, 117,  31],
    [221, 189,  55],
    [240,  98,  99],
    [142, 126, 100],
    [219, 166, 218],
    [112, 155,  26],
    [198, 209, 131],
    [169, 135, 150],
    [114,  47, 217],
    [224, 223,  53],
    [220,  45, 134],
    [ 32, 211, 140],
    [109,  67, 108],
    [146,  43,  91],
    [231, 230, 120],
    [113, 226, 247],
    [105,  63,  52],
    [241, 238, 242],
    [124,  46, 156],
    [ 95,  78,  96],
    [ 70,  46,  63],
    [116, 143, 227],
    [116, 123, 111],
    [  1,  44,  19],
    [  3, 236,  51],
    [207, 216, 205],
    [ 26, 154,  22],
    [165,  39, 167],
    [199, 200, 208],
    [101,  36, 100],
    [ 43,  57, 202],
    [242,  20,  99],
    [ 56,  28, 157],
    [124,  35, 113],
    [ 29, 160,  27],
    [211, 204, 210],
    [124, 113,  46],
    [106,  43, 204],
    [ 96,  62,  77],
    [227, 137, 116],
    [ 73,  41,  72],
    [ 36, 203, 142],
    [235,  64, 240],
    [ 48,  49,  64],
    [ 42,  41,  74],
    [214, 212, 207],
    [183,  42, 184],
    [210, 169, 211],
    [140, 170, 176],
    [104, 105,  69],
    [193, 122, 168],
    [ 50, 123, 187],
    [ 89,  96,  90],
    [ 66,  65, 107],
    [179,  89, 180],
    [119, 101, 120],
    [ 68,  63, 104],
    [234,  93, 227],
    [ 16,  15,  85],
    [209, 129,  49],
    [ 15,  14,  86],
    [107,  55,   9],
    [120, 100, 121],
    [153, 145,  22],
    [178,  88, 179],
    [197,   6, 196],
    [ 89,  88,  96],
    [135, 138, 136],
    [138, 215, 172],
    [218, 115, 219],
    [ 41,  42,  81],
    [  5, 195,  51],
    [ 57,  43,  61],
    [208, 171, 199],
    [ 41,  81,  38],
    [224,  53, 225],
    [ 24, 144, 110],
    [105,  52,  66],
    [118, 229, 117],
    [227,  34, 234],
    [ 66, 107,  69],
    [ 10, 109, 151],
    [219,  48, 235],
    [183,  62, 191],
    [142, 129, 126],
    [116, 111, 143],
    [118, 117,  50],
    [223, 222,  52],
    [ 94,  19, 141],
    [222, 221,  65],
    [196,   3, 197],
    [ 45, 220,  44],
    [156,  70, 139],
    [188, 122, 245],
    [139,  71, 162],
    [149, 170, 150],
    [122, 188, 196],
    [206, 216,  92],
    [164,   2, 167],
    [242, 141, 241],
    [  0, 164,  37],
    [ 11,  72,  12],
    [ 12,  38,  13],
    [ 70,  63,  71],
    [ 31, 226, 111],
    [ 36, 101, 205],
    [203, 206, 165],
    [126, 209, 217],
    [ 98, 165,  97],
    [237, 220, 218],
    [237, 239, 241],
    [210, 214, 169],
    [140, 171,  32],
    [241, 125, 237],
    [179,  86, 178],
    [180,  85, 179],
    [181,  84, 180],
    [182,  83, 181],
    [194, 201, 182],
    [177, 137, 132],
    [184,  76, 183],
    [185,  61, 184],
    [186,  57, 185],
    [216, 212, 186],
    [192, 214, 187],
    [139,  34, 156],
    [218,  79, 237],
    [147, 123, 177],
    [ 45,  44,   4],
    [208, 201,  32],
    [ 98,  64, 129],
    [192, 213, 138],
    [235,  59, 219],
    [141, 242,  97],
    [ 97,   2, 141],
    [240,  75, 235],
    [229,  24, 228],
    [ 31,  25, 226],
    [230,  23, 229],
    [231,  22, 230],
    [232,  26, 231],
    [233, 112, 232],
    [244, 189, 243],
    [189, 221, 190],
    [222,  28, 221],
    [223,  27, 222],
    [224,  29, 223],
    [225,  30, 224],
    [113, 247, 225],
    [ 99,  60, 240],
    [213, 147, 215],
    [ 60,  20, 166],
    [192, 187, 213],
    [243, 112, 244],
    [244, 233, 245],
    [245, 128, 188],
    [188, 114, 174],
    [134, 131, 220],
    [174, 217, 236],
    [236, 198, 134],
    [215, 177,  58],
    [156, 143, 124],
    [ 25, 110,   7],
    [ 31, 228,  25],
    [264, 356, 368],
    [  0,  11, 267],
    [451, 452, 349],
    [267, 302, 269],
    [350, 357, 277],
    [350, 452, 357],
    [299, 333, 297],
    [396, 175, 377],
    [280, 347, 330],
    [269, 303, 270],
    [151,   9, 337],
    [344, 278, 360],
    [424, 418, 431],
    [270, 304, 409],
    [272, 310, 407],
    [322, 270, 410],
    [449, 450, 347],
    [432, 422, 434],
    [ 18, 313,  17],
    [291, 306, 375],
    [259, 387, 260],
    [424, 335, 418],
    [434, 364, 416],
    [391, 423, 327],
    [301, 251, 298],
    [275, 281,   4],
    [254, 373, 253],
    [375, 307, 321],
    [280, 425, 411],
    [200, 421,  18],
    [335, 321, 406],
    [321, 320, 405],
    [314, 315,  17],
    [423, 426, 266],
    [396, 377, 369],
    [270, 322, 269],
    [413, 417, 464],
    [385, 386, 258],
    [248, 456, 419],
    [298, 284, 333],
    [168, 417,   8],
    [448, 346, 261],
    [417, 413, 285],
    [326, 327, 328],
    [277, 355, 329],
    [309, 392, 438],
    [381, 382, 256],
    [279, 429, 360],
    [365, 364, 379],
    [355, 277, 437],
    [282, 443, 283],
    [281, 275, 363],
    [395, 431, 369],
    [299, 297, 337],
    [335, 273, 321],
    [348, 450, 349],
    [359, 446, 467],
    [283, 293, 282],
    [250, 458, 462],
    [300, 276, 383],
    [292, 308, 325],
    [283, 276, 293],
    [264, 372, 447],
    [346, 352, 340],
    [354, 274,  19],
    [363, 456, 281],
    [426, 436, 425],
    [380, 381, 252],
    [267, 269, 393],
    [421, 200, 428],
    [371, 266, 329],
    [432, 287, 422],
    [290, 250, 328],
    [385, 258, 384],
    [446, 265, 342],
    [386, 387, 257],
    [422, 424, 430],
    [445, 342, 276],
    [422, 273, 424],
    [306, 292, 307],
    [352, 366, 345],
    [268, 271, 302],
    [358, 423, 371],
    [327, 294, 460],
    [331, 279, 294],
    [303, 271, 304],
    [436, 432, 427],
    [304, 272, 408],
    [395, 394, 431],
    [378, 395, 400],
    [296, 334, 299],
    [  6, 351, 168],
    [376, 352, 411],
    [307, 325, 320],
    [285, 295, 336],
    [320, 319, 404],
    [329, 330, 349],
    [334, 293, 333],
    [366, 323, 447],
    [316,  15, 315],
    [331, 358, 279],
    [317,  14, 316],
    [  8, 285,   9],
    [277, 329, 350],
    [253, 374, 252],
    [319, 318, 403],
    [351,   6, 419],
    [324, 318, 325],
    [397, 367, 365],
    [288, 435, 397],
    [278, 344, 439],
    [310, 272, 311],
    [248, 195, 281],
    [375, 273, 291],
    [175, 396, 199],
    [312, 311, 268],
    [276, 283, 445],
    [390, 373, 339],
    [295, 282, 296],
    [448, 449, 346],
    [356, 264, 454],
    [337, 336, 299],
    [337, 338, 151],
    [294, 278, 455],
    [308, 292, 415],
    [429, 358, 355],
    [265, 340, 372],
    [352, 346, 280],
    [295, 442, 282],
    [354,  19, 370],
    [285, 441, 295],
    [195, 248, 197],
    [457, 440, 274],
    [301, 300, 368],
    [417, 351, 465],
    [251, 301, 389],
    [394, 395, 379],
    [399, 412, 419],
    [410, 436, 322],
    [326,   2, 393],
    [354, 370, 461],
    [393, 164, 267],
    [268, 302,  12],
    [312, 268,  13],
    [298, 293, 301],
    [265, 446, 340],
    [280, 330, 425],
    [322, 426, 391],
    [420, 429, 437],
    [393, 391, 326],
    [344, 440, 438],
    [458, 459, 461],
    [364, 434, 394],
    [428, 396, 262],
    [274, 354, 457],
    [317, 316, 402],
    [316, 315, 403],
    [315, 314, 404],
    [314, 313, 405],
    [313, 421, 406],
    [323, 366, 361],
    [292, 306, 407],
    [306, 291, 408],
    [291, 287, 409],
    [287, 432, 410],
    [427, 434, 411],
    [372, 264, 383],
    [459, 309, 457],
    [366, 352, 401],
    [  1, 274,   4],
    [418, 421, 262],
    [331, 294, 358],
    [435, 433, 367],
    [392, 289, 439],
    [328, 462, 326],
    [ 94,   2, 370],
    [289, 305, 455],
    [339, 254, 448],
    [359, 255, 446],
    [254, 253, 449],
    [253, 252, 450],
    [252, 256, 451],
    [256, 341, 452],
    [414, 413, 463],
    [286, 441, 414],
    [286, 258, 441],
    [258, 257, 442],
    [257, 259, 443],
    [259, 260, 444],
    [260, 467, 445],
    [309, 459, 250],
    [305, 289, 290],
    [305, 290, 460],
    [401, 376, 435],
    [309, 250, 392],
    [376, 411, 433],
    [453, 341, 464],
    [357, 453, 465],
    [343, 357, 412],
    [437, 343, 399],
    [344, 360, 440],
    [420, 437, 456],
    [360, 420, 363],
    [361, 401, 288],
    [265, 372, 353],
    [390, 339, 249],
    [339, 448, 255]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced (no pun intended) the same problem and found that the mediapipe/mediapipe/modules/face_geometry/data/ folder contains usable reference data. In the end, what worked best was using geometry_pipeline_metadata_landmarks.pbtxt and regexping the index_buffer entries (ie, replace "index_buffer:" and adding comma's between the numbers.)
This produced a matching index buffer.

(There is also a canonical .obj file, but using those indices did not give me a perfect mesh)

Answer (score 0):

The triangles list missed one triangle below, plz add this : )

```
[255, 339, 448]
```

Answer (score 0):

The image below shows a complete mapping of facial landmarks.
Source - https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/face_landmarker

[image]